# node-js возможно ли подключить к html

Tags: html, node.js

Всё описано в заголовке.
Возможно ли node.js подключить к html сайту?
Если да, то как?

Comment: Что значит подключить к html ? html - это разметка, NodeJS это сервер.

Comment: Ты хотя бы опиши суть? В чем идея? Какой смысл? Что имеется ввиду подключить к `html  nodejs`

Comment: @Air есть подозрения что человек хочет апач(или что он там себе представляет сервером для "HTML") заменить на NodeJS

Comment: По сути ты можешь подключить, допустим `server.js`  подключить в `html` `<script src="ПУТЬ к файлу"></script>`, но это не будет работать, интерпретатор не поймет твой скрипт

Comment: Есть такой фреймворк / `npm` модуль `express`([click][1]) для `Node.js`. Так-то на нём бекенд писать, настраиваешь маршрутизацию по страницам и так далее, и хопа у тебя рабочий сайт. Судя по всему тебе это надо.

Но так-то, вопрос твой непонятен совсем.


  [1]: https://expressjs.com/ru/

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, мне кажется, автор сам не знает чего хочет...

Comment: @Air вполне возможно =)